# nested if ternary condition javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am trying to do this condition as ternary operation:

```
if(a>10){
  if(a===15){
   console.log("++++"
  }else{
   console.log("----")
  }
}else{
   console.log("a is 12");
}
```

This is a simple model what I have to do with ternary. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  Also, what are you trying to use a ternary conditional operator for exactly?  Nothing here produces/returns a value.

Comment: Nested ternaries are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do this? It will actually make your code a lot less readable. Just because you *can* do it doesn't mean you *should* do it.

Comment: @David I believe he wants to have just one call to `console.log()` with the ternary as the argument.

Comment: The general form of the conditional operator is `cond ? true-case : false-case`. E.g. `a === 15 ? "++++" : "----"` would return `"++++"` if the condition is true and `"----"` otherwise.

Comment: If you're going to use nested ternaries, put parentheses around the nested levels and it should work as expected.

Comment: Isn't any way that we can do nested-if with ternary operator?
This is a simple way that I want to do. I want to do this:
{
            this.state.comments ? <Comments comments={this.props.comments} /> : this.props.id.map((postId) => {
              return postId.postId.filter(id => id === this.props.location.state.data)
            })
          } : " " : ""

Comment: @FabioPlaka: The code you're showing in that comment doesn't appear to be in any way related to the code shown in the question.  So far all you've asked is if it's possible to nest ternary operators, to which the answer is "yes".  Have you tried?  Can you edit the question to clarify what exactly you're trying in your code and how it's failing?